# Angularjs deep $watch not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

Even after activating Deep watch in the factory it is not triggering. How to solve this issue so that an event can be triggered on 'name' value change?

Javascript Code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope,testFactory) {
  $scope.obj = testFactory.obj;

});

app.controller('SecondCtrl',function($scope,testFactory){
  $scope.obj = testFactory.obj;
  $scope.valueChange = testFactory.valueChange;
});

app.factory('testFactory', ['$rootScope',function ($rootScope) {

    var factory = {};

    factory.obj = { 'name':'John Doe'};

    $rootScope.$watch(factory.obj,function(){
        alert('Value Changed');
    },true);

    factory.valueChange = function(){
      if(factory.obj.name == 'John Doe'){
      factory.obj.name = "Jane Doe";
      }
      else
      {
        factory.obj.name = "John Doe";
      }
    };

    return factory;

}]);
```

Html Code:

```
  <body >
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <h4>Value bound with FirstCtrl and factory</h4>
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.name"/>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4>Value from SecondCtrl. This shows that the bind between factory and controller is working</h4>
    <p>{{obj.name}}</p>
    <h4>Value updated directly in the factory</h4>
    <button ng-click="valueChange()">Change Value</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LhHOa2NehWGVEfpHfKJQ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
    return factory.obj;
}, function(){
    alert('Value Changed');
}, true);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IZ4esIiHSq0hNlMEB6ac?p=preview)

Better solution would be to watch for changes in controller instead of factory:

```
app.controller('SecondCtrl',function($scope,testFactory){
    $scope.obj = testFactory.obj;
    $scope.valueChange = testFactory.valueChange;
    $scope.$watch('obj', function () {
        alert('Value changed');
    }, true);
});
```

In this case `$scope.obj` and `testFactory.obj` points to same object in memory. So no matter which one you will watch for.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why watch in controller is better than in factory? Currently the value can be changed by different controllers, so having a single watch in factory makes sense, right?

Comment: You can check value change in `valueChange` function in factory, why do you need watch there?

Comment: Oh no-no. That was just an example. The 'value' to be monitored is changed directly in the controller not through a function in the factory. I need to trigger a function in case the 'value' is changed by any controller and hence I need $watch in the factory. This would be better I think instead of having multiple watch functions in different controllers.